# JSONP on play framework 2.0

Tags: jsonp, playframework-2.0

I am preparing a web service which needs cross-domain ajax call with JSONP. Play 2.0 RC3 (scala) is used. But I can't get the callback invoked.

How to handle it?

Thanks.

Comment: Finally, I find the solution. Just need to parse the request to get the callback function name and return 

    Ok(fuctionName + "(" + data + ")").as("text/javascript")

That's it.